# Phinx and PHPUnit

Tags: php, sqlite, phpunit, dbunit, phinx

I'm running PHPUnit 5, with DBUnit 2.0.3, and Phinx 0.8.2. I'm trying to set up a test with a SQLite in memory database:

```
abstract class ApiTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{
    protected $pdo;

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($this->pdo, ':memory:');
    }

    public function getDataSet()
    {
        return $this->createFlatXMLDataSet(dirname(__FILE__) . '/DataSets/TestDataSet.xml');
    }

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:', null, null, [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ]);

        $configArray = require('phinx.php');

        $configArray['environments']['test'] = [
            'adapter'    => 'sqlite',
            'connection' => $this->pdo
        ];

        $config = new Config($configArray);

        $manager = new Manager($config, new StringInput(' '), new NullOutput());

        $manager->migrate('test');

        $this->getDataSet();
    }
}
```

This is my test:

```
class DatabaseTest extends ApiTest
{
    public function testCodes()
    {
        $count = $this->getConnection()->getRowCount('user');

        dd($count);
    }
}
```

This is my data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<dataset>
    <user id="1" username="johnsmith" password="pwdpwd" token="tokenhere" token_validity="1" deleted="0" />
</dataset>
```

When I run the test I get a row count of `0`. I'm expecting a row count of `1`. I know the migration is working because if I enter a dummy table name it errors with "row not found".

Comment: How many rows do you get when asking PDO directly?

Comment: Are you actually inserting any data at any point? I only see that you run the migration, not that you're inserting into or seeding it.

Comment: @Dormilich Asking directly returns 1 row

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The data is inserted with `$this->getDataSet();` in the `setUp` function.

Comment: @Dormilich Actually, although `rowCount` returns `1`, if I perform a `fetchAll` it returns an empty array. Hmm...

Comment: In such cases I'd never rely on PDO's rowCount(). Instead use SQL's COUNT().

Comment: @Dormilich Yes, that is returning `0`

Comment: I think this is just because of missing `parent::setUp` in your test case, it should do some arrangements -- can be seen [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit/blob/master/src/TestCaseTrait.php#L66)

Comment: @xmike Thanks, but this doesn't change the result.